# change the value of parameter passed by reference

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can I change the value for the parameter passed by Reference in a method inside the class?

ie:

```
Public Class Setting

    Public Sub New(Optional ByRef target as String = Nothing)
        _target = target
    End Sub

    Private Sub Go()
        If Not IsNothing(_target) Then
            _target = "New Value"
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim var1 as String = "Old Value"
Dim s as New Setting(var1)
s.Go()
```

After s.Go() I'm expecting to get:

```
var1 = "New Value"
```

But I'm getting:

```
var1 = "Old Value"
```

Thanks

Comment: why not just change it to ByVal if you want to change it, or better yet, use a function?

Comment: This might be a somewhat special case because strings are immutable.  Do you get the same behavior if you changed target to an Integer?

Comment: I don't think you can make it work with your current design. Either pass the ByRef param in the Go method or don't use ByRef at all, and return a new value.

Answer (score 1):

use wrapper class

For example, I use a StringBuilder as a wrapper class.

```
Public Class Setting
    Dim _target As StringBuilder
Public Sub New(Optional ByRef target as StringBuilder = Nothing)
    _target = target
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeValue()
    If Not IsNothing(_target) Then
        _target.Clear()
        _target.Append("New Value")
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Go()
    ChangeValue()
End Sub

End Class
Sub Main()
    Dim var1 as New StringBuilder("Old Value")
    Dim s as New Setting(var1)
    s.Go()
    Console.WriteLine(var1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ...

```
Public Sub New(Optional ByRef target as String = "")
    _target = target
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeValue()
    If _target.Length = 0 Then
        _target = "New Value"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it has to do string being immutable as stated by Mike C in the comment

[Strings (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228362.aspx)

> String objects are immutable: they cannot be changed after they have
>   been created. All of the String methods and C# operators that appear
>   to modify a string actually return the results in a new string object.

Testing with Integer is not apples to apples as Integer is a value type

I suspect = makes a deep copy
This is C#
Even this does not append _s to s

```
public class Sclass
{
    public Sclass(ref string s)
    {
        s += "Sclass";
        string _s = s;
        _s += "_s";
    }
}
```